# Missing View Data option in SSDT project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

VS2013 Premium update 5 12.0.40629
SSDT 12.0.50730

i can view the table design, but View Data is missing, google show me nothing related

Comment: You can't view data on a table in an SSDT project which is essentially a collection of scripts. I think what you're looking for is in the Server Explorer pane where you can connect to a database server and view data on that server.

Comment: funny, SS-Data-Tools can't view data. anyway, put this as answer, i will marked it as answer. tq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't view data on a table in an SSDT project which is essentially a collection of scripts.

I think what you're looking for is in the Server Explorer pane where you can connect to a database server and view data on that server. In this pane, when you expand until you see your table, right-click the table and select Show Table Data.